# Get image path from OpenShift server. Spring MVC. JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, openshift

I have got a trouble while getting photo path from OpenShift server.
I have got a Spring MVC app that have deployed at OpenShift server.
There, every user could download there profile pics. I do it this way.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/updateinfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAvatar(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Principal principal) {
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return "redirect:/user";
    }

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            String relativeWebPath = "";
            String absoluteFilePath = "/var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/app-root/data/";
            String name = file.getOriginalFilename();
            // String name=file.getOriginalFilename();
            System.out.println(absoluteFilePath);
            String path = absoluteFilePath + "/" + name;
            File convFile = new File(absoluteFilePath + "/" + name);
            this.usersService.addUserAvatar(principal.getName(),"/var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/app-root/data/"+name);
            System.out.println(convFile.getAbsolutePath());
            file.transferTo(convFile);
            System.out.println("You have uploaded file");
            return "redirect:/user";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to upload");
            return "redirect:/user";
        }
    }
    return " redirect:/user";
}
```

I'm putting my files to this path at OpenShift server

```
/var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/app-root/data/
```

And after that i'm putting to database a path to this image that needed to get at user's page

```
this.usersService.addUserAvatar(principal.getName(),"/var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/app-root/data/"+name);
```

When i'm opening user's page it shows me 404 error that `GET https://appName-domain.rhcloud.com/haine/var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/app-root/data/vr833vqI_wc.jpg`

How to put a current path to my photos that it could have an access? Help pls!

Answer (score 0):

This how-to explains why it is difficult to serve user-uploaded files from a java application on openshift, and what code you can use to remedy the situation: https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift

Comment: if you are speaking about https://blog.openshift.com/multipart-forms-and-file-uploads-with-tomcat-7/ this topic, there are uncorrect answer!
Cause in there tutorial says that i need to update **context.xml** `<Context path="/" aliases="/static=/var/lib/openshift/12592ddfd6824bd88a45a3dd111b2ced/app-root/data">
` at this line! it doesn't work, because this file doesn't connect with a server! Correct answer is to update `<Context docBase="/var/lib/openshift/PROJECT_ID/app-root/data" path="/data" />` at ** .openshift/config/server.xml**