# Get path to app/root dir at OpenShift. Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, path, openshift

I deployed my **.war** file at OpenShift server.
I uploaded some images to **app-root/data/** dir. And when i'm trying to get path to this image and to put it into img source `<img src='var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/app-root/data/vr833vqI_wc.jpg'>` it gives me 404 error `https://appname-domain.rhcloud.com/haine/var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/app-root/data/vr833vqI_wc.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
How to get correct path to my img?

Comment: Is app-root/data within your webapp?

Comment: @AlanHay, yeah! i created web-app at OpenShift, commited there my **.war** file from another app that i needed to deploy and it's a storage of web-app that i created at openshift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get image path from OpenShift server. Spring MVC. JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186343/get-image-path-from-openshift-server-spring-mvc-jsp)

Comment: @corey112358, yeah! but no answer there

Comment: If your previous question is not answered yet, that is not a reason to post basically the exact same question again.

Comment: @corey112358, not agree, cause it goes to bottom in list of questions but this questin will be in top for some time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload photos to OpenShift. Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160011/upload-photos-to-openshift-spring-mvc)